# Using multiple relationships in one query

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I cant seem to get this query to work. All I want to do is find nodes in my db that matches both `Category` and `Keyword`.

```
match (n:SiteEntry)-[r:ClassifiedAs]->(c:Category)<-[h:HasKeyword]->(k:Keyword) 
where c.Label=~'.*Business.*' AND k.Keyword=~'a.*' 
return n.Url, c.Label, k.Keyword limit 100
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you have any errors ? Except that the query is not optimized I can see already that the relationship :HasKeyword is using both directions <- -> which I don't think is permitted.

Comment: As @ ChristopheWillemsen says, `<-[h:HasKeyword]->` is not legal in Cypher. You can have at most one arrow exiting from a relationship instance. Interestingly, at least with neo4j 2.1.5, your query does not generate an error, but apparently hangs the neo4j server.

Comment: Can you provide your dataset? Then it would be easier to help you figure out what's wrong.